# function returning undefined when i pass in data from different function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I Have two function and I'm trying to pass data from one functions to the other one by calling the function 2 and passing in the data from function 1.
I keep getting undefined when calling the second function.

fist function makes the api call

```
import { get } from '../helpers/api'

export function getAllPosts() {
    get('/fetch-posts')
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.success) {
                console.log(res)
                getAllPostsData(res.data.posts)
            }
        })
}
```

when calling this function it returns undefined.

```
export function getAllPostsData(data) {
    return data
}
```

Comment: is `res.data.posts` something other than `undefined` in the output of `console.log(res)` - do you realise that `function getAllPostsData(data) {
    return data
}` is redundant? and also that `getAllPosts` doesn't return anything - so the code you posted is quite pointless

Comment: What will be the result of console.log(res.data.posts); if it is undefined try to change it to console.log(data.posts);

Comment: @JaromandaX  it console logs the data properly. that's why I can't understand why it returns undefined in the `getAllPostsData function`

Comment: how do you know it returns undefined there? if you change your code in the first function to `var x = getAllPostsData(res.data.posts); console.log(x);` is the output `undefined`? - I suspect the issue is that `getAllPosts` doesn't return anything

Comment: @JaromandaX even if i change it to `getAllPostsData(res)` it will still return undefined.

Comment: that's where you are completely mistaken ... it's `getAllPosts` that will return `undefined` whereas `getAllPostsData` will return exactly what you pass to it (which is why that function as written is not needed)

Comment: @JaromandaX in my vue component i `console.log(getAllPostsData())` becuase `data` is undefined.

Comment: `console.log(getAllPostsData())` exactly, you've passed NOTHING (i.e. data will not be defined) to `getAllPostsData` and it returns that - can you see how `getAllPostsData` function is absolutely redundant?  `var x = getAllPostsData(1);` is just `var x = 1;` - because getAllPostsData returns what you pass to it ... it doesn't "rememeber" the asynchronously executed  `getAllPostsData(res.data.posts)` for you to access synchronously

Comment: I suspect your real issue is that you are having trouble understanding how to deal with asynchrony

Comment: did you even try my suggested change to the `getAllPosts` that will prove to you that `getAllPostsData` wont return `undefined` (as long as you don't call it with `undefined` of course ... to hammer the point again, `getAllPostsData` returns what you call it with ... `getAllPostsData(1)` - returns 1, `getAllPostsData('hello')` returns 'hello` and `getAllPostsData()` returns `undefined`